# Logback with spring-boot: use ${user.home} does not work

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I can't figure out why logback does not take into account the variable defined in the corresponding `application-{env}.yml` file.
Here is the content of `logback-spring.xml` file:

```xml
<configuration>

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />

    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_FILE" source="logging.file"
                    defaultValue="localhost"/>
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE}"/>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_FILE}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>

            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history capped at 3GB total size -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.example.demospringweb" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <springProfile name="default">
        <root level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </root>
        <logger name="com.demospringweb" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        </logger>>
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="qa, prod">
        <logger name="com.demospringweb" level="WARN" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        </logger>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

And here is the content of the `application.yml` file:

```yaml
greeting: Default greeting
password: default-pass
logging:
  path: ${user.home}
  file: ${logging.path}/demo_localhost
  max-history: 30
  level:
    com:
      example: debug
    org:
      hibernate: ERROR
      springframework:
        web: DEBUG
```

When I start the spring-boot app, it does not create a required log file.

### UPDATE

I removed completely `spring-logback.xml` and kept profile-specific properties in corresponding application.yml files.
Here is the `application.yml` file and it never writes (creates) a log file:

```yaml
greeting: Default greeting
password: default-pass
spring:
  application:
    name: demo-spring
  logging:
    file: demo-dev
    pattern:
      file: "%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger.%M - %msg%n"
      console: "%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger.%M - %msg%n"
    level:
      root: debug
      org:
        hibernate: ERROR
        springframework:
          web: DEBUG
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out how to achieve that.

1. Remove `logback-spring.xml` or `logback.xml` file if there is any. In this case, Spring boot will use the default values defined by Logback if they are not overridden in your `application.yml` (or `application.properties`) file.
2. Create `application.yml` and `application-prod.yml`. file (you can add as many as you want, depending on how many environments you are going to have.
3. Here is the content of `application.yml` file used for development:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: demo-spring
greeting: Development greeting
password: dev-pass
logging:
  pattern:
    console: "%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger.%M - %msg%n"
  level:
    root: debug
    org:
      hibernate: ERROR
      springframework:
        web: debug
    com:
      example:
        demospringweb: info
```

In this case, the output will be printed to the console only using the provided pattern. The root log level is set to `debug` but the package `com.example.demospringweb` is set to `info`(you can use either UPPERCASE or lower cased versions of log levels).

4. Create a profile-specific `application-prod.yml` file that will be used when the app is started with the `prod` activated:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: demo-spring
greeting: Production greeting
password: prod-pass
logging:
  path: ${user.home}/logs
  file: ${logging.path}/prod.log
  total-size-cap: 100MB
  max-history: 10
  max-file-size: 5MB
  pattern:
    console: off
    file: "%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n"
    rolling-file-name: ${logging.path}/plage_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}_%i.log
  level:
    root: info
    org:
      hibernate: ERROR
      springframework:
        web: warn
    com:
      example:
        demospringweb: info
```

As you see, when starting the app with `spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=prod` Spring Boot will use the values defined in `application-prod.yml` file:

- write the logs to the file `prod.log` created in the user `$HOME/logs` directory. We also defined a rolling policy to keep 10 days history of max 5Mb by file max. The total size of all the log files is set to 100 Mb. Once it is achieved, the oldest file will be removed.
  We also defined different log levels (root and by package).

To check how the logging varies depending on the active profile, take a look at the `GreetingController`:

```java
package com.example.demospringweb.controllers;

import com.example.demospringweb.models.Greeting;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

@RestController
public class GreetingsController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GreetingsController.class);

    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @Value("${greeting}")
    private String greeting;

    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting() {
        LOGGER.debug("This is a debug message");
        LOGGER.info("This is an info message");
        LOGGER.warn("This is a warn message");
        LOGGER.error("This is an error message");
        String message = greeting + "/pwd: " + password;
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), message);
    }
}
```

Voilà.